# In Spring mvc How to add add set values to mysql

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

My goal :

In Spring MVC I have  to save mobile phone contact list into database.
example:

```
       phone1  sonia 2554654 work
                     2554654  home
```

multiple **phone_number** with multiple **phone_Number** **type**

## contacts table

```
id,
contact_name
phone_number
phone_type
```

in my java class I have

```
public class ContactMobile {

  private String type;
  private String number;

  public ContactMobile() {
  }

  public ContactMobile(String type, String number) {
    super();
    this.type = type;
    this.number = number;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public String getNumber() {
    return number;
  }

  public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
  }

}
```

and here I use **SET** for phone number and type

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "_contact")
public class MobileContact {

  private String id;
  private String             fullname;
  private Set<ContactMobile> mobileNumbers;



  public MobileContact(String fullname, Set<ContactMobile> mobileNumbers) {
    super();
    this.fullname = fullname;
    this.mobileNumbers = mobileNumbers;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "Id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "fullname")
public String getFullname() {
    return fullname;
  }

  public void setFullname(String fullname) {
    this.fullname = fullname;
  }


  public Set<ContactMobile> getMobileNumbers() {
    return mobileNumbers;
  }

  public void setMobileNumbers(Set<ContactMobile> mobileNumbers) {
    this.mobileNumbers = mobileNumbers;
  }

public MobileContact() {
    super();
}

}
```

I am using hibernate to store data..
my question is in my **MobileContact** class in

```
public Set<ContactMobile> getMobileNumbers() {
        return mobileNumbers;
      }
```

what annotation I have to use here to save multiple phonenumbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MobileContact` entity has many `ContactMobile`, it is a OneToMany relation. In your `ContactMobile` table, you should has a field for the id of `MobileContact`, like `mobile_contact_id`, and set the join column on that field as below in your `ContactMobile`:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LEZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "mobile_contact_id")
private Set<ContactMobile> mobileNumbers;
```

You can get the detail about the relation in [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077819/java-se/understanding-jpa-part-2-relationships-the-jpa-way.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Embeddables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables) (instead of Entities) for very simple value objects like `MobileContact` (then they do not need an ID, and the are no just simple value objects without own identity)

```
@Embeddable
public class ContactMobile {... 
    //implement an equals and hashcode method!
}


public class MobileContact {
    ...

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<ContactMobile> mobileNumbers;
    ...
}
```

@See [Java Persistence/ElementCollection](http://Java%20Persistence/ElementCollection)